# The communication between Flask and JS doesn't go well

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, flask

## Background

As an exercise for making image recognition AI app,
I'm trying to test some tools used for developing it.

For making a simple image recognition AI app,
I decided taking the following approach:

- Using webcam related API of HTML5 for taking picture of subject(frontend)
- Using Python and some of its ML related libraries for the core function of this app.(backend)
- Using JavaScript's `fetch API` and Python's `Flask` for communication between frontend and backend.

The tools I'm going to use would be `fetch API` and `Flask` and  `HTML + JavaScript`,
so I tried to make a sample code for testing how these tools work.

## Problem

The communication between JavaScript and Flask through http doesn't work.
The problems might be

- Failing to send image data from JavaScript(frontend) to Flask(server)
- Something's wrong with coping with json strings data.
- Something's wrong with Flask code and JavaScript code for http communication

More in detail, please take a look at the following codes.

## files and codes

- `app.py`: Flask code which defines server-side functions.
- `templates`: The directory in which the files `app.py` returns to a client are placed.
- `index.html`: HTML + JS code for camera and sending http request to Flask.
- `post.html`: Just showing "hello" for checking if the communication between front and server goes well.

[file composition]

```
　├── app.py
　└── templates
    　└── index.html
      └── post.html
```

[app.py]

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, redirect, send_from_directory, request
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)  
 
@app.route('/')  
def home():
    return render_template("index.html");

@app.route("/tmp",methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data = request.get_data()
    if not data:
       return "no data"
    else:
       return render_template("post.html")
    
  
if __name__ =="__main__":  
    app.run(debug = True)
```

[index.html]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Camera Test</title>
  <style>
  canvas, video{
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>HTML5カメラ</h1>

<video id="camera" width="300" height="200"></video>
<canvas id="picture" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<form>
  <button type="button" id="shutter">シャッター</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn-send">send</button>
</form>

<audio id="se" preload="auto">
  <source src="camera-shutter1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script>

function sendServer(url, param){
  fetch(url, param)
    .then((response)=>{
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json)=>{
      if(json.status){
        alert("送信に『成功』しました");
        setImage(json.result);    //json.resultにはファイル名が入っている
      }
      else{
        alert("送信に『失敗』しました");
        console.log(`json.status${json.status}`)
        console.log(json)
        console.log(`[error1] ${json.result}`);
      }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      alert("送信に『失敗』しました");
      //console.log(json)
      //console.log(json.result)
      console.log(`[error2] ${error}`);
    });
}


window.onload = () => {
  const video  = document.querySelector("#camera");
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#picture");
  const se     = document.querySelector('#se');

  /** カメラ設定 */
  const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      facingMode: "user"   // フロントカメラを利用する
      // facingMode: { exact: "environment" }  // リアカメラを利用する場合
    }
  };

  /**
   * カメラを<video>と同期
   */
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then( (stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => {
      video.play();
    };
  })
  .catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  });

  /**
   * シャッターボタン
   */
   document.querySelector("#shutter").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // 演出的な目的で一度映像を止めてSEを再生する
    video.pause();  // 映像を停止
    se.play();      // シャッター音
    setTimeout( () => {
      video.play();    // 0.5秒後にカメラ再開
    }, 500);

    // canvasに画像を貼り付ける
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  });
   
   document.querySelector("#btn-send").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    // Canvasのデータを取得
    const pic = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  // DataURI Schemaが返却される

    // 送信情報の設定
    const param  = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({data: pic})
    };

    const SAVE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/tmp";
    // サーバへ送信
    console.log(param)
    
    sendServer(SAVE_URL, param);
  });

};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[post.html]

```
<body>
hello
</body>
```

The exact bug I am having now is

- ** The core problem might happen at `sendServer` function in `index.html`**
- ** No json data is attached with http-response from Flask**

What is wrong?

Any information would be appreciated.

### Edited

The status code popping up when I sent http request by pressing "send" button was `202`, so the sending request (by POST method) might be succeeded. In that case, what is wrong? I'm guessing the `sendServer` function is wrongly implemented or the treatment of json is wrong.

```
C:\Users\Naoki\yaruzo>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 955-089-816
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2021 13:18:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2021 13:19:01] "GET /camera-shutter1.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2021 13:19:01] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2021 13:19:47] "POST /tmp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

### Edited 2

As the answerer's suggestion, I tried removing `JSONStringify` and putting the image data directly into the `body` of the http request, but now I caught another error.
[modified]

```
//index.html
const param  = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      body: {data: pic}
    };
```

[New error]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

The error is at the `.catch` part of `sendServer` function.

```
function sendServer(url, param){
  fetch(url, param)
    .then((response)=>{
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json)=>{
      if(json.status){
        alert("送信に『成功』しました");
        setImage(json.result);    //json.resultにはファイル名が入っている
      }
      else{
        alert("送信に『失敗』しました");
        console.log(`json.status${json.status}`)
        console.log(json)
        console.log(`[error1] ${json.result}`);
      }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      alert("送信に『失敗』しました");
      //console.log(json)
      //console.log(json.result)
      console.log(`[error2] ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect that the problem is on either Flask or sendServer side, Itoo think the problem is on either of these two, but I can't confirm what seems to be wrong. So some questions needs to be asnwered, can you confirm if the request is being sent and what status code is being returned (you can check that either from flask debug or browser debug under network tab) browser should show status code for trying to send a request.

### First solution

So if status code is 404 then something wrong is in the request, usually it's either the data or the sent CORS which should be passed with the request header. I suspect the second option, so I'd suggest you add the following in your code and try again sending your image (replace port with the port you're sending requsts from or just keep localhost)

```py
#app.py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,resources={r"/*":{"http://localhost:{port}":"*","http://localhost":"*"}})
```

### Second solution

In case the first solution didn't work and status code is still 404, then the problem should be in the sent data. Try taking out (JSON.stringify) in params, to look something like this,

```js
//index.html
const param  = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      body: {data: pic}
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and I'm sorry for the late reply. The status code popping up when I sent http request by pressing "send" button was `202`, so the sending request might be succeeded. In that case, what is wrong? I'm guessing the `sendServer` function is wrongly implemented or the treatment of json is wrong. Though it is not `404`, I would like to try the second solution you suggested.